# What's the <C-w> key in Vim?

Tags: vim

I see a lot of talk about different keys (`<C-R>`, `<C-j>`, and `<C-w>`) in Vim and I'm wondering if there's a list somewhere (`:help`?) that tells what they are. I figured out `<C-R>` is Enter ("carriage return", I suppose) but often the others don't make immediate sense.

Comment: Or better: `:help key-notation`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are not keys, they are keys associated with the control key. `<C-j>` means "Press j while pressing control".

`<C-R>` is not carriage return, it's the redo command. `<CR>` is carriage return. `<C-F>` is page up, `<C-B>` is page down, ...

Answer (score 27):

So many key-bindings to learn in `vim`, you'd better learn how to use the `:help`.
There are some tips to get help quickly:

`Ctrl-W` in normal mode:

```
:h ^w
```

`Ctrl-W` in insert mode:

```
:h i^w
```

`Ctrl-W` in visual mode:

```
:h v^w
```

`Ctrl-W` in command mode:

```
:h c^w
```

Open help in another tabpage:

```
:tab h ^w
```

Comment: Been using VI since I was 3 months old and never have I ever seen the `:h [mode]^[key]` help usage. Neither the carrot or the mode. This needs to be included in more answers to questions.

Answer (score 3):

The control keys. For instance, using `<C-w> h` (or `j`, `k`, `l`) will toggle between open buffers.

`<C-j>` will move you down a line. Also, I could be wrong, but I believe the carriage return is `<CR>` (not `<C-R>`).